# How to send Jinja variables to Django View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, jinja2

I have a view in HTML whereby it displays a list of table with attendees;

```
        <table>
            {% for people in Attendees %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ people.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ people.name }}</td>
                <td>
                   <a id='deleteAttendeeButton' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

The table has a delete button for all entries and when clicked, I am using AJAX for a GET request as per below;

```
$("#deleteAttendeeButton").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/modifyAttendee/?id={{ people.id }}',
            type: 'GET',
        })
});
```

I want to use AJAX to send the people.ID variable to view so that the view can determine what object to delete in the database. However, the issue is I cannot seem to pass in a jinja variable in AJAX.

Am I missing something in my AJAX statement? If not, what would be an ideal solution?

Note: I do not want to use 'href' in the button because I do not want to reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't work like that. The template tags are evaluated at render time, but you need the ID of the element that was clicked. You can use the `data` element to hold the ID and get it back in the JS.

There are a few other things wrong here too; in particular, HTML element ids need to be unique, but you are using the same one for every link in the loop. You should use a class instead.

```
<a class='deleteAttendeeButton btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-people_id="{{ people.id }}">Delete</a>
```

...

```
$(".deleteAttendeeButton").on("click", function () {
    var people_id = $(this).data('people_id');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/modifyAttendee/?id=' + people_id,
        type: 'GET',
    })
```

(Note, unless you have specifically configured it, Django does not use Jinja; this is almost certainly Django template language which is similar but not the same. It doesn't affect your problem, though.)

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel! I was trying to find a solution for this for days!